# Search & Replace SQL Database Meta Value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have some custom Wysiwyg Editor Fields, where I put some data in HTML. Now, I tried to change some string from these fields. Example: 
If found this string in anywhere of meta value, it will be replaced.

**Find:** `<td class="column-1">Address</td> <td class="column-2"></td>`

**Replace with:** `<td class="column-1">Address</td> <td class="column-2">Not Available</td>`

I tried using codes. But, it's not working.

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, '<td class="column-1">Address</td> <td class="column-2"></td>', '<td class="column-1">Address</td> <td class="column-2">Not Available</td>') WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%<td class="column-1">Address</td> <td class="column-2"></td>%'
```

Comment: Hope your `<` was not converted to `&lt`.

Comment: Will you please explain? Is there any possibility? Actually, I don't have much knowledge about MySQL..